# Does Azure Queue Storage behave the same as MSMQ?

Tags: azure, msmq, azure-queues, azure-storage

I have a few applications that I have built that leverage MSMQ on a Windows Server.  I would like to port these to Azure-based Web Applications which helps me with some of the security and trust-barrier challenges I have faced in the past.

My question is, can I expect that the Message Queue aspects of Windows Azure storage will behave the same as MSMQ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, not really.  While both are queueing solutions, you will find that Windows Azure queues don't have the same guarantees that MSMQ will have (for good reason).  For instance, WAQ supports a delivery model of 'at least once' versus 'exactly once'.  It also uses a 2PC model where you must pop and then delete a message.  It is also not involved in transactions like MSMQ can handle.  However, for cloud queuing scenarios, some of these considerations matter less.  There are other nuances as well (message TTL, invisibility, renewals, storage time, etc.) that differ.

It might be easier to answer more completely if you explain what features your queueing needs *must* have.  Also, keep in mind that AppFabric has a queueing service that also might be appropriate depending on what you really need.

Comment: Thanks.  I am using MQ as a way of decoupling my CRM system from a WS exposing by a courier service.  So I have a service that polls the WS and write to a MQ, and another service that polls the queue and updates the CRM system.  I'm moving from a local-network install of CRM to a cloud implementation and I think based on your explanation I can move to a work-role/WAQ implementation to handle the polling.